# Not understanding the operation pre and post increment

Tags: c, increment, decrement

I have following C program and I'm not understanding the output of this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=8;

    printf("%d\n", a++);

    printf("%d\n", ++a);

    printf("%d\n", a*a);

    return 0;
}
```

The value of first **printf** is **8** and the value of second **printf** is 10!! But how??

Comment: a is 8; `printf("%d\n", a++);`, a increments to 9 _after_ printing.  `printf("%d\n", ++a);`  a increment to 10 _before_ printing.

Comment: @Scotia It's easier to read the docs, or your textbook, for a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `a++` is postfix notation, the value is first incremented, but the **previous** value is returned, which is then passed into `prinf`.
- `++a` is prefix notation, the value is first incremented before it's passed into `printf`.

Your code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
int a = 8;
printf("%d\n", a);
a++;

a++;
printf("%d\n", a);
printf("%d\n", a*a);
return 0;
```

But it's closer to this (note I'm using the `,` operator, which evaluates each sub-expression but only returns the final sub-expression):

```
int a = 8; int aTemp;

// a++
printf("%d\n", (aTemp = a, a = a + 1, aTemp) );

// ++a
printf("%d\n", (a = a + 1) );
```

Comment: Actually `a` is incremented *before* the call to `printf` is evaluated. `a++` just evaluates to the old value of `a`, not the new value.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, I was just rephrasing it to be simpler to understand.

Comment: @sepp2k I've reworded my answer and provided a better equivalent expression.

Comment: @Scotia it represents the intermediate value of `a++` that would exist in a CPU register or stack-space during the method-call.

Comment: How this line `printf("%d\n", (aTemp = a, a = a + 1, aTemp) );` is printing 8???

Comment: @Scotia See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Answer (score 1):

a++ will use a in the current statement (in this case output to screen) and then increment "a" after the statement.

++a will increment "a" before the statement is executed.